# Correct application of the CFL Pumping Lemma

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, pumping-lemma

I came across this question about showing that the language $L = \{w \epsilon \{a, b, c\}^*: n_a(w) + n_b(w) = n_c(w)\}$ is context-free but not linear in the book by Peter Linz. That is easily doable by the separate pumping lemma for linear languages (as given in Linz's book), but my question is different.

Evidently this is a CFL, and a pushdown automaton can be constructed for it. But if I apply the pumping lemma for CFLs, I find that I'm able to pump strings that don't belong to the language, which would mean that the language is not a CFL. Clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Going by the "game-like" format given in Linz, say you pick $w = a^mb^mc^{2m}$, $|w| \ge m$. The adversary can choose a number of decompositions $w = uvxyz$, they can look like -:

- $v = a^k, y = a^l$: The case where $|vxy|$ is contained within the $a$'s of the string. Pump $i = 0$, and then $w_0 = a^{m – (k + l)}b^mc^{2m}$ cannot be in the language since the equality no longer holds.
- $v = a^k, y = b^l$: The case where $v$ is in the $a$ section, $x$ spans across the $a$'s and $b$'s, and $y$ is in the $b$ section. Again, pump $i = 0$. $w_0 = a^{m – k}b^{m – l}c^{2m}$ cannot be in the language.

There are more cases like these. Where am I going wrong in the application of the CFL PL?

Comment: To correctly apply the pumping lemma and show that the language is not context free, **all** partitions $uvxyz$ of your chosen string should have the property that pumping them leads to strings that do not belong to the language.

Comment: That makes sense. Is my application of the lemma then correct here? - Say the adversary selects $v = b^k$ and $y = c^l$. Are they allowed to select $k = l$? In that case, the word becomes $w_i = a^mb^{m + (i - 1)k}c^{2m + (i - 1)l}$ on pumping. If $k = l$, no matter what $i$ I choose, the word will always be in the language because we're removing/adding equal parts from/to $b$ and $c$.

This also means I can't just conclude from one case violation that the language is not a CFL. Real bummer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pumping lemma for CFL states that if $L$ is a CFL, there exists a constant $N \ge 1$ such that for all $\omega \in L$ with $\lvert \omega \rvert \ge N$ there is a division $\sigma = u v w x y$ with $\lvert v w x \rvert \le N$ and $v x \ne \varepsilon$ such that $u v^k w x^k y \in L$ for all $k \ge 0$.

(The pumping lemma for regular languages is similar, the discussion below applies with minor changes).

You want to prove by contradiction that $L$ is not a CFL. So you assume $L$ is a CFL, and get a contradiction to the lemma. This means, in detail:

- As $L$ is a CFL, it satisfies the lemma. In particular, there is a constant $N$ such that...
- As the lemma states *all* long strings in $L$ can be divided, you are free to pick one that is easy to work with.
- The lemma states there is *some* division of $\omega$ such that.... for *all* $k \ge 0$...; to contradict the lemma you have to prove *no* division works. In practice, you take a given division of your $\omega$ (*any* division) and for it pick some $k$ for it that doesn't give a string in the language. You might need to divide this into cases.

What happens for strings that don't belong to the language, or are shorter than $N$, is completely irrelevant. It might be that some strings can be pumped, that some values of $k$ work for all strings, ... What is crucial is that for *one* string $\omega$ (the one you picked) *no* division works with *one* value of $k$ (again, the one you picked). As the lemma asserts it works for *all* long enough strings, with *some* division for *all* $k$, one counterexample is enough. Infinite examples prove nothing.

Comment: I finally understand what they mean by "one counterexample". This makes it much clearer and now I see where I was going wrong. Thank you!